# Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain partition table

Tags: partition, table

I am unable to booting with my laptop getting this error No operating system after booing with Live cd if i give this command  fidsk -l getting below error.

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo fdisk  -l

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table
mint@mint ~ $
```

Can any one help how to recovery this partition table with out losing my data...?

Please help me to come out from this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is in MBR format? Have you tried gpartd? -- Also it could be a LVM physical volume which would have no partition table.

Comment: Maybe it is also an invalid [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) ([UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)) partition.

Comment: I think, too that you are using a GPT, as @jofel mentioned. you will need to add a `bios-boot` partition and reinstall grub.

Comment: What does `gdisk -l /dev/sda` say? What about `file -s /dev/sda`? What makes you think that the disk still contains valid data?